# Notification without "heads up"

Tags: android, android-notifications, heads-up-notifications

I am trying to create a notification that has a high priority (a chatting app) but my client requested that there will be no "heads up" view for it.

I have tried creating an empty layout for a `RemoteViews` to set as the `Notification.headsUpContentView` but still nothing.

Here is what I've tried:

```
    Intent target = new Intent(this, PushConsumedBroadcastReceiver.class);
    target.putExtra(PushConsumedBroadcastReceiver.PUSH_TYPE, PushConsumedBroadcastReceiver.PUSH_TYPE_REMINDER);

    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_BASE, target, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentIntent(pending)
    .setContentTitle(item.getNotificationText())
    .setStyle(new BigTextStyle().bigText(item.getNotificationText()).setSummaryText("thepoosh looks good"))
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.g_icon_white)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
    .setTicker(item.getNotificationText())
    .build();

    if(VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notification.headsUpContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.empty_heads_up);
    }
    notification.sound = null;
    notification.ledARGB = 0;
    notification.vibrate = new long[0];

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(CODE_ONE_DAY_REMINDER, notification);
```

**empty_heads_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `PRIORITY_MAX`, you can disable the Heads-Up notification using the following code starting with API 21:

```
notification.headsUpContentView = new RemoteViews(Parcel.obtain());
```

Comment: The notifications stops showing when this is added, tested on Android Pie 9.0

Comment: Android 10: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)' on a null object reference" And the notification does not show up all.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a heads up notification is a part of [the definition of a high-priority notification](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html):

> If a notification's priority is flagged as High, Max, or full-screen, it gets a heads-up notification.

If you don't want a heads-up notification, you do not want a high-priority notification.

Note that you users can opt to disable heads up notifications or lower the priority of your notifications themselves, but this is an option solely for the user.